# Assign existing footprint to existing component in Circuit Maker?

Tags: altium, footprint

I found the following two components in Circuit Studio that I am using in my design:

AOD407:

[image]

And IRLR8726:

[image]

The manufacturer recommended footprint is exactly the same for both, and they use the same 3D model in Altium. The trouble is, whoever did the footprint for the 407 on Octopart departed from the recommended footprint, making their own instead. This is undesirable for me, as my design needs symmetry.

**Left:** 407 Footprint (non-standard, custom), **Right:** 8726 Standard Footprint

[image]

In the parts page, I can add new footprints to the part, and I added one, but it starts with a blank template. I do NOT want to copy and paste the standard footprint into the template. This is too much effort for a professional tool. How can I import existing footprints in the footprint editor? This will allow me to standardize my footprints for these and other parts.

- I am using [Circuit Maker](https://documentation.circuitmaker.com/display/CMAK/PCB_Dlg-SystemOptions_Frame((PCB+Editor+-+General))_CM), which is essentially the community version of Altium.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have multiple footprints for each component.
[image]
http://documentation.circuitstudio.com/display/CSTU/Component+Management+in+CircuitStudio

Under the component, In the models tab, click add, then browse the pcb library for the footprint. You can delete the old footprint or I believe there is some way to select it. You can also do this for one component only if done through the PCB editor and not the library

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for! Don't know how I missed it. Thanks! By any chance to you know how to open a footprint/schematic symbol from the vault and modify it, then save it as a new footprint?

Comment: The way I've done this in the past is to create a new part, open the old part and manually copy the schematic library and the pcb library. There might be a better way to do that however.

Comment: Sadly someone edited my question and changed it from CircuitMaker to CircuitStudio in the title and body. I didn’t catch that in your answer because the part properties windows look almost identical between the two apps, only I don’t have the buttons you have in your image. I found out how to do this in CircuitMaker however. I even found a way to import the symbols directly. This post should still be helpful though. I bet some people want to do this in CircuitStudio too 